# how to show real tags from a htmlspecialchars_decode?

Tags: php, zend-framework, html-entities, zend-filter

i'm creating a cms in php using zend framework where i choose to save at some part html templates to ease redesigning of the views and all.Now to save those templates(views, sidebars) i had to use `Zend_Filter_Input` with `Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities(array('quotestyle' => ENT_QUOTES)`

one of the reasons is security, the second is that i use freeRTE to ouput the template for editing, and that freeRTE is very sensitive to `quotes` so i had to do something.

Now i'm hustling because when i try to output the template back or worst show it in its layout to the public, it shows raw html with tags ,html_entity_decode and htmlspecialchars_decode  could not do a thing.example instead of showing the image it show the following on the page :

```
<div id="welcome"> <div id="welcome_img"><img src="/images/welcome.jpg" alt="welcome" /></div></div>
```

any clue? it anyone has experienced this please do share the knowledge on that.thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you provide some example of what is happening? The problem is that when you echo them in your view (echo $this->escape($tempalte)) you don't get html tags?

Comment: Hi marcin i've updated the post to respond to your question.in the page i expect to see the real image displaying not the html code.that's what happened in the view :  `echo html_entity_decode($this->output["content_template"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use htmlentities for filter when you save HTML. It will replace <, > and & plus all the replaceable chars.

**Edit:**
Remove HTMLEntities filter from saving, because saving HTML as-is would be the whole point of template-editor.

If you want to add some security related features, remove  tags from the HTML and every other html tag that you find harmful! (embed?)

Comment: so should i remove the HtmlEntities filter as a tradeoff? thanks

Comment: Yes, you don't need that. If anyone can edit the templates and you want protection, you should eliminate certain tag-types with regex, like <script>, but not escaping every HTML. The whole point of a template-editor is to edit and save templates.

Comment: i just did `str_replace` for the `single quote`.i would add the script regex bit to it.thanks.can you edit your previous post so that i mark it correct?

Comment: Ok, edited. Yes, if freeRTE is the reason for quotes, a simple replace is enough.